# How to reference weak in 1 line?

Tags: swift, weak-references

How can I make a weak reference without declaring an extra variable?

E.g. how can I write this in 1 line:

```
    weak var weakSelf = self
    self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = weakSelf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether a property is `weak` or `strong` is an attribute of the property.  It isn't an attribute of the value being assigned to it.

In your case, the `delegate` property of your `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` must be declared as `weak` for this to do anything useful.

In the class `UIGestureRecognizer`, the delegate is indeed `weak`:

```
@property(nullable,nonatomic,weak) id <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> delegate; // the gesture recognizer's delegate
```

So you just need to do:

```
self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
```